# save dataset as netCDF and also save attributes in Python (xarray)

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I generated new data and save first as dataset (.to_dataset).

```
U_reg = U_reg.to_dataset(name = 'U')
V_reg = V_reg.to_dataset(name = 'V')
T_reg = T_reg.to_dataset(name = 'T')
```

Then I created attributes for each variable

```
U_reg.attrs['long_name'] = 'eastward_wind'
V_reg.attrs['long_name'] = 'northward_wind'
T_reg.attrs['long_name'] = 'Air Temperature'
```

Then merged the data as :

```
new_data= xr.merge([U_reg,V_reg,T_reg])
```

For finally save as a netCDF:

```
new_data.to_netCDF('new_data.netcdf')
```

Nevertheless when I open and look at each variable, the attributes are not available.

Is there other way to assign new attributes and have them I the new netCDF generated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you were adding the `long_name` attribute to the dataset attributes, rather than the attributes for the individual arrays. If you add the attributes before you convert to a dataset (or directly to the dataset variables), you should get your expected output:

```
U_reg = xr.DataArray(np.random.random((5, 6, 7)), dims=("lon", "lat", "time"))
V_reg = xr.DataArray(np.random.random((5, 6, 7)), dims=("lon", "lat", "time"))
T_reg = xr.DataArray(np.random.random((5, 6, 7)), dims=("lon", "lat", "time"))

U_reg.attrs['long_name'] = 'eastward_wind'
V_reg.attrs['long_name'] = 'northward_wind'
T_reg.attrs['long_name'] = 'Air Temperature'

ds = xr.Dataset({
    "U": U_reg,
    "V": V_reg,
    "T": T_reg
})

ds.info()
```

```
xarray.Dataset {
dimensions:
    lon = 5 ;
    lat = 6 ;
    time = 7 ;

variables:
    float64 U(lon, lat, time) ;
        U:long_name = eastward_wind ;
    float64 V(lon, lat, time) ;
        V:long_name = northward_wind ;
    float64 T(lon, lat, time) ;
        T:long_name = Air Temperature ;

// global attributes:
```